# Take n-th first events of specific class and everything else

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

Say I have

```
public abstract class Event {}

public final class A extends Event {}
public final class B extends Event {}
public final class C extends Event {}
```

Now, with an `Observable<Event>`, how could I filter it so that only `n`-th emission of `A` and all of `B` and `C` are passed onto the stream.

Something like this maybe?

```
myObservable.publish(shared ->
  Observable.merge(
    shared.ofType(A.class).take(n),
    shared.notOfType(A.class) // this does not exist
  )
)
```

Is there a good way to tackle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use instanceof and invert the logic

```
@Test
void name() {
    Observable<? extends Event> just = Observable.just(
            new A(),
            new B(),
            new A(),
            new B(),
            new C(),
            new A(),
            new C()
    );

    int n = 2;

    Observable<? extends Event> publish = just.publish(shared ->
            Observable.merge(
                    shared.ofType(A.class).take(n),
                    shared.filter(o -> !(o instanceof A))
            )
    );

    publish.test()
            .assertValueCount(6);

}
```